# Install PHP on a IBM i5/os V6R1

Tags: php, zend-framework, ibm-midrange, httpserver

this is my first question here, but very often I've been saved by this website on my programming issues.
This time I'm trying to do something that I'm a total newbie in...

I need to Install PhP on a IBM iSeries (i5/os) V6R1.
I don't know much about AS400/iSeries... right now I only managed to run the http server.
We have never used this machine for web-serving purposes, we normally use another (web)server connected through an ODBC to query the iSeries tables...

Searching the net, I've found the "Bringing PHP to Your IBM eServer iSeries Server" redpaper, but it's a very old (2003) paper, it's for php 4.3 and includes a patch to be able to compile Php for iseries... so i suppose that if I download a newer version of php this won't work because I don't have a patch that does the same for php 5.x...

Then I found information about a web that had binaries for php on iseries, i5php.net but it seems this web is no longer working... THEN... I found information about Zend, I found another IBM paper in in which they talked about installing Zend Server (I don't know if by just installing that it would include Php) but it seems this is not a free app anymore, or it's divided now between something called Zend Framework and Zend Server...

As you can see, I'm a total newbie here and I'm really lost...

It would be great to have a step by step explanation and commands to use, but I know that would be too much to ask! so if at least you could help me understand what I'm getting into and give me a hint on how to get php running, I would be really grateful...

And sorry for my probably awful english.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely want to go with the Zend package..AFAIK it's the only PHP distro that is supported by IBM.

http://www.zend.com/en/solutions/modernize-ibm-i

Also, might want to look here:
http://lists.midrange.com/mailman/listinfo/web400

The Zend guys and other users hang out there.

Comment: By searching with 'zend ibm i' I got this as the first result: http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/php/

Comment: Thanks!, but all the links on Zend's site send me to "buy" options, no free options... the web linked by Buck,had an invalid link to download something called "Community edition". but then, thanks to the web400 link (by Charles), I discovered:
http://archive.midrange.com/web400/201304/msg00021.html
it says, Zend-Server-CE was rebranded to "IBM i Basic Edition" so I search for that on zend's web and found this. 
http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/editions-ibm-i#production
There IS a Basic edition, but when I download says:
Thank you for Downloading the 30-day Zend Server Free Trial
Help? :(

Comment: I found another one, says free version 6.3 and it doesn't say about the trial as the other one... I'll try with that, sorry and I hope this works.
http://ww2.zend.com/en/products/server/free-edition

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You want http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/downloads#IBM%20i You get a trial of the full "Zend Server" but if you don't licenses it it reverts to the basic/CE edition.

Comment: Oh, well I already downloaded and installed free version, but it's ok, the good news is that I got it running, now I suppose I have to learn proper ways to configure the server, but it's running great right now, thanks a lot for the help. :)